# How to check if the input is letter 'l', 'h' or 'c'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming so take it easy on me. 
I am having issues understanding this kind of if statements and while loops:

```
command = input()
if command != "l" or command != "h" or command != "c"
    print("Please insert l, h or c: ")
    command = str(input("l, h or c: "))
else:
    print("working")
```

I don't understand why `'h'` or `'c'` are not being checked. When I try this on my IDE I get:

```
l
Please insert l, h, or c: 
l, h or c:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your boolean logic mixed up.

If `command` is `l`, then it is not equal to `h` or `c`; that makes your `if` statement true:

```
False (!= l) or True (!= h) or True (!= c) == True
```

`or` is True when one of the two options is true, and for your test at least 2 out of 3 options are always going to be true, possibly 3.

You want to use `and` instead:

```
if command != "l" and command != "h" and command != "c":
```

or use `not` on 3 or tests with `==` equality:

```
if not (command == "l" or command == "h" or command == "c"):
```

or, much better and more readable, use `not in` to test against a set of options:

```
if command not in {'l', 'h', 'c'}:
```

Comment: If checking membership in a group of constants, why the need or the set? Seems fine to just use a tuple or list. I cant remember if sets of literal values are equally optimized

Comment: @jamylak: because it is the fastest option, in Python 3 that's optimised as a frozenset stored as a constant.

Comment: @jamylak: see [Should I use 'in' or 'or' in an if statement in Python 3.x to check a variable against multiple values?](//stackoverflow.com/a/24678205) and [Tuple or list when using 'in' in an 'if' clause?](//stackoverflow.com/a/25368371)

Comment: @jamylak set membership is `O(1)` in the average case, unlike lists/tuples which are `O(n)`.

Comment: The set approach is also very good if you have many commands to check, instead of chaining lots of `or` clauses together.

Comment: @RoadRunner Yes everyone knows that but it wasnt my question, i was asking about this specific case which is answered by the link commented by MartijnPieters (for python 3.2 and up it shows this is the best approach)

Comment: But actually now Im questioning whether it really is faster in practice as there were no timings posted on tuples vs sets for approx 3 or so constants. Maybe some time i will test this

Comment: @jamylak didn’t you read the answers I posted then? There’s a benchmark right there. With 3 constraints no less.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
command = input()
if command not in {'l','h','c'}:
    print("Please insert l, h or c: ")
    command = input("l, h or c: ")
else:
    print("working")
```

The in will check if the command is inside that list of strings

Comment: Better: use `if command not in {'l', 'h', 'c'}:`; Python optimises that case and you get a O(1) test.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how is one better than the other?

Comment: See  [Should I use 'in' or 'or' in an if statement in Python 3.x to check a variable against multiple values?](//stackoverflow.com/a/24678205) and [Tuple or list when using 'in' in an 'if' clause?](//stackoverflow.com/a/25368371)

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok

Comment: @MartijnPieters one question _why_ should you use a set?

Comment: Because membership testing in a set is faster, a O(1) operation vs. a O(N) operation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What are these O(1) and O(N) things?

Comment: That’s Big O notation: https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: so you should use a set because it is almost a millisecond faster?

Comment: @Hippolippo Yes, it's good practice for when it actually makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

do `if command not in {"l","h","c"}:` and it will check if what you typed is in that set